JMS(AMQP) to PubSub
I'm working on setting up a GCP dataflow job that pushes JMS messages to PubSub. I set up the job using the "JMS to PubSub" flex template using my queue (amqp). Apparently the job doesn't recognize queues using AMQP protocols.
Is there another way to go about this? I've looked into possibly making my own flex template but I haven't had much luck. I've also looked at possibly making a python script but python doesn't work well with JMS (Who would've guessed).
This is the only link I've found associated with the JMS to PubSub
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/jms-to-pubsub
Thank you!
